# How do I refactor these two C# functions to abstract their logic from the specific class properties they are acting on?

Tags: c#

I have  two functions whose underlying logic is the same but in one case it sets one property value on a class and in another case it sets a different one. How can I rewrite the following two functions to abstract away as much of the algorithm as possible so that I can make changes in logic in a single place?

### SetBillingAddress

```
private void SetBillingAddress(OrderAddress newBillingAddress)
{
    BasketHelper basketHelper = new BasketHelper(SiteConstants.BasketName);
    OrderAddress oldBillingAddress = basketHelper.Basket.Addresses[basketHelper.BillingAddressID];

    bool NewBillingAddressIsNotOldBillingAddress = ((oldBillingAddress == null) || (newBillingAddress.OrderAddressId != oldBillingAddress.OrderAddressId));
    bool BillingAddressHasBeenPreviouslySet = (oldBillingAddress != null);
    bool BillingAddressIsNotSameAsShippingAddress = (basketHelper.ShippingAddressID != basketHelper.BillingAddressID);
    bool NewBillingAddressIsNotShippingAddress = (newBillingAddress.OrderAddressId != basketHelper.ShippingAddressID);

    if (NewBillingAddressIsNotOldBillingAddress && BillingAddressHasBeenPreviouslySet && BillingAddressIsNotSameAsShippingAddress)
    {
        basketHelper.Basket.Addresses.Remove(oldBillingAddress);
    }

    if (NewBillingAddressIsNotOldBillingAddress && NewBillingAddressIsNotShippingAddress)
    {
        basketHelper.Basket.Addresses.Add(newBillingAddress);
    }

    basketHelper.BillingAddressID = newBillingAddress.OrderAddressId;
    basketHelper.Basket.Save();
}
```

And here is the second one:

### SetShippingAddress

```
private void SetShippingAddress(OrderAddress newShippingAddress)
{
    BasketHelper basketHelper = new BasketHelper(SiteConstants.BasketName);
    OrderAddress oldShippingAddress = basketHelper.Basket.Addresses[basketHelper.ShippingAddressID];

    bool NewShippingAddressIsNotOldShippingAddress = ((oldShippingAddress == null) || (newShippingAddress.OrderAddressId != oldShippingAddress.OrderAddressId));
    bool ShippingAddressHasBeenPreviouslySet = (oldShippingAddress != null);
    bool ShippingAddressIsNotSameAsBillingAddress = (basketHelper.ShippingAddressID != basketHelper.BillingAddressID);
    bool NewShippingAddressIsNotBillingAddress = (newShippingAddress.OrderAddressId != basketHelper.BillingAddressID);

    if (NewShippingAddressIsNotOldShippingAddress && ShippingAddressHasBeenPreviouslySet && ShippingAddressIsNotSameAsBillingAddress)
    {
        basketHelper.Basket.Addresses.Remove(oldShippingAddress);
    }

    if (NewShippingAddressIsNotOldShippingAddress && NewShippingAddressIsNotBillingAddress)
    {
        basketHelper.Basket.Addresses.Add(newShippingAddress);
    }

    basketHelper.ShippingAddressID = newShippingAddress.OrderAddressId;
    basketHelper.Basket.Save();
}
```

My initial thought was that if I could pass a class's property by refernce then I could rewrite the previous functions into something like

```
private void SetPurchaseOrderAddress(OrderAddress newAddress, ref String CurrentChangingAddressIDProperty)
```

and then call this function and pass in either basketHelper.BillingAddressID or basketHelper.ShippingAddressID as CurrentChangingAddressIDProperty but since I can't pass C# properties by reference I am not sure what to do with this code to be able to reuse the logic in both places.

Thanks for any insight you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass lambda expressions:

```
private void SetPurchaseOrderAddress(OrderAddress newAddress, Func<string> addressIDGetter, Action<string> addressIDSetter)
```

Call it like this:

```
SetPurchaseOrderAddress(newAddress, () => basketHelper.BillingAddressID, a => basketHelper.BillingAddressID = a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Send in a Func and an Action, one to get the property out, and another to set it again.

```
private void SetPurchaseOrderAddress(OrderAddress newAddress, 
          Func<BasketHelper, int> getAddId, Action<BasketHelper, int> setAddId) {}
```

Which would give something like:

```
SetPurchaseOrderAddress(address, 
    bh => bh.Basket.Addresses[bh.BillingAddressID],
    (bh,s) => bh.BillingAddressID = s);
```

Comment: Note that you can't pass properties by reference because under the hood they are actually two methods (getter and setter), I know because I tried this afternoon! (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529782/c-property-and-ref-parameter-why-no-sugar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegates to create a method that takes some simple behavior (such as setting a value of the property) as an argument. In C# 3.0, you can easily create a delegate using lambda expressions and in C# 2.0 you can do similar thing using anonymous delegates.

In your example, you would write a method that takes `Action<BasketHelper>` delegate - the delegate allows you to specify some operation that should be done with the `BasketHelper` after you initialize it and before you save it:

```
private void SetBasketProperty(Action<BasketHelper> action)  { 
  BasketHelper basketHelper = new BasketHelper(SiteConstants.BasketName); 
  // Code that is repeated for all similar methods

  // Invoke the specific action    
  action(basketHelper);
  basketHelper.Basket.Save(); 
}
```

To call this method in C# 3.0 you can write something like this:

```
SetBasketProperty(basketHelper => {
    basketHelper.ShippingAddressID = newShippingAddress.OrderAddressId;
  });
```

The lambda expression simply provides the code that you want to run before calling `Save`.