# Access private members of the generic instance within a generic class via reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, entity-framework-6, extension-methods

I have looked at potentially duplicate questions, and this problem is not answered in any of them including [Accessing Properties Through Generic Type Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059420/accessing-properties-through-generic-type-parameter)

**TLDR; `typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.NonPublic)` does not work within a generic class when `propertyName` of T is not declared public, even when the NonPublic BindingFlag is set. Is there a workaround for this?**

I have implemented an extension method that produces an IOrderedQueryable from a supplied string that contains the desired columns for sorting in an Entity Framework environment. The goal was to allow Order By clauses to be written in string form such as "+Age,+State,-Name" and produce the necessary expression to sort Entity Framework results by Age, State, and Name (descending), instead of having to write:

`.OrderBy(m=>m.Age).ThenBy(m=>m.State).ThenByDescending(m=>m.Name)`.

The problem comes in when I try to access a class property that is marked internal. I cannot seem to find any way to force reflection to find that internal property.

In this particular case I have a datetime field in the database which is stored UTC but I want the end user to work with it in local time, so the value startTime, an internally scoped property is bound to the database and StartTime serves as a public accessor and provides access to the startTime value performing the necessary mapping to local time. I have a class defined as follows:

```
public class TimeInterval { 
   //other properties...
   internal startTime { get; set; } // bound to database, stores time in UTC
   public StartTime { 
      get { /*convert startTime to local time*/; } 
      set { /*convert value back to UTC and store in startTime*/;  }
   }
}
```

With EF I can write `.OrderBy( m=>m.startTime )` and it works as expected; of course I cannot use `.OrderBy( m=>m.StartTime )` because it is derived.

Within my extension function whose signature is

```
static public IOrderedQueryable<T> ParseOrderBy<T>( 
   this IQueryable<T> query, 
   string orderBy 
   )
```

which I would call using :

```
var query = query.ParseOrderBy<TimeInterval>( "startTime" );
```

my call to obtain the property reference to build a lamba expression returns null.

```
var property = typeof( T ).GetProperty( "startTime", BindingFlags.NonPublic );
```

`property` comes back null for anything that is not explicitly public.

The extension method is in the same namespace and assembly as the classes I expect it to operate.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267277/get-private-properties-method-of-base-class-with-reflection

Comment: You don't even need reflection for this task - [`Expression.Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341554(v=vs.110).aspx) will do that for you.

Comment: @GertArnold. Sorry I forgot to mention that. I use reflection all time time, so I am aware of the binding flags. I did specify BindingFlags.NonPublic, and it still comes back NULL

Comment: @RuiJarimba No, sorry that is not the answer. I use reflection all the time and in all other cases it works. It seems that when used in a generic class as I describe, it does not allow you to access non-public members.

Comment: @IvanStoev I missed that possibility because none of the examples I saw used the actual property name as a parameter to the Expression.Property method but instead used the GetProperty method to use the PropertyInfo overload. If you want to post your comment as an answer I will mark it accepted. However I would still like to know why this aspect of generics does not allow reflection to access private members yet Expression logic does.

Comment: @IvanStoev It appears there must be a bug in Expression.Property() when supplying a string identifying the property name. I gave it startTime and it keeps finding StartTime. If I added another internal property startTime2, it finds that perfectly.

Comment: @Bill There is nothing special. `BindingFlags.NonPublic` is not enough, you must combine it with `BindingFlags.Instance`. Normally you should use `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic`. Cheers.

Comment: @IvanStoev This will be here for posterity: I am getting old. As mentioned previously I use reflection all the time for all sorts of things. I kept thinking that Instance was the default behavior in terms of bindings.