# Delphi 7 : Converting (serializing?) an object to TByteDynArray (for SOAP)

Tags: delphi

I use Delphi 7 and import from a WDL file to create a SOAP client. Delphi generates interface code with the published functions from the WSDL and the types (classes) of parameters for those functions.

Delphi has determined that something like this

```
  Message = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FMessageID: Int64;
    Ftimestamp: TXSDateTime;
    Fevent: eventType;
    FmagicNumber: WideString;
    FDataPart: DataPart;
  published
    property MessageID: Int64 read FMessageID write FMessageID;
    property timestamp: TXSDateTime read Ftimestamp write Ftimestamp;
    property event: eventType read Fevent write Fevent;
    property magicNumber: WideString read FmagicNumber write FmagicNumber;
    property DataPart: DataPart read FDataPart write FDataPart;
  end;
```

should be send as a TByteDynArray ...

```
function  sendMessage(const theMessage: TByteDynArray; 
                      const data: DataPart): WideString; stdcall;
```

which necessitates me converting an object to a TByteDnyArray, which - beings  Delphi n00b - I am doing this by

```
  theMessageArray := TByteDynArray(theMessage);
```

When I look at the object in the debugger, then it contains pointers (to the `Ftimestamp` and `Ftimestamp`), and when I look in the TByteDynArray I see the self same pointer values. So, it seems that "cast" is not what I wanted. How do convert my object to the TByteDynArray which is required? (and which, presumably "inlines" the objects pointed to by pointers)

I presume that there is a standard approach for this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the parent class for a way to stream the data. objectinstance.savetostream or so. It probably will iterate over the published membes and write them to a stream.

Use this to write it to a memory stream, which is roughly a class around a memory block (like tdynbytearray). Then use memorystream.size and setlength to allocate the tbytedynarray to the proper size, and copy the bytes from the memorystream to the newly created array:

```
 // (Untested)

 memstream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
 objectinstance.SaveToStream(memstream);
 setlength(mybytearray,memstream.size);
 if memstream.size>0 then
    move (pansichar(memstream.memory)^,mybytearray[0],memstream.size);
```

Comment: +1 for replying, but will that "cast" it to a TByteDynArray ?  I need too be sure that it will can be used as the parameter to a SOAP call.

Comment: No, casting a class to anything but another class is not possible. This is called streaming, which is the usual way for this to be done

Comment: +1 Marco, yes, I know, but what is worrying me is that I might have to write, try call the remote procedure and fail. That would leave a lot of tricky debugging. It seems to me that if Delphi itself, when parsing a WSDL file, generates an interface that takes a TByteDynArray instead of an object, then there should be a standard way to convert (and I have googled & can't find any useful examples)

Comment: The parent class TRemotable does not seem to have any methods to save to stream. I guess that I will have to code my own

Comment: hmm, isn't there a ready-made TCustomMemoryStream descendant that SetPointer's to the data-pointer-position of the start of a TByteDynArray? (if there isn't it's not that hard to make)